# How to constrain randomness

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm drawing a random shape with vertices onto a canvas.
Sometimes the shape is very narrow and small.
Is there a way to constrain the randomness so this wont happen.
As I am very new to p5 any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks for your time and help

```
let noOfShapes = 3;

function setup(){
    createCanvas(1240, 1754);
    noLoop();
    background(0,230)
    colorMode(RGB)
    rectMode(CENTER);
    strokeWeight(3);

}

function draw(){
    //fill(56, 37, 34);

    for(let x = 0; x < noOfShapes; x++) {
      beginShape();
      stroke(255);
      fill(25, 255, 255,100);
      //noFill();
        for(let y = 2; y < 6; y++) {
          vertex(random(10,width), random(10,width))
          // vertex(random(10,width), random(10,width))
          // vertex(random(10,width), random(10,width))
          // vertex(random(10,width), random(10,width))
        }
      endShape(CLOSE);
    }
    stroke(255);

    for(let x=20; x<= width; x = x+20){
        blendMode(DODGE);
        //fill(200,200,200)
        stroke(255);
        beginShape();
          vertex(x, 0)
          vertex(x, height+20)
        endShape();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list of random numbers for the x and y coordinates:

```js
rx = []; ry = [];
for (let y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
    rx.push(random(10, width-20));
    ry.push(random(10, height-20));
}
```

Compute the difference between the minimum ([`min`](https://processing.org/reference/min_.html)) and maximum ([`max`](https://processing.org/reference/max_.html)) for each list:

```js
drx = max(rx) - min(rx);
dry = max(ry) - min(ry);
```

Define a threshold an repeat the process as long any of the differences is below the threshold:

```js
let threshold = 200;
do {

  // [...]
}
while (drx < threshold || dry < threshold)
```

The algorithm can be further improved, by taking into account the distance between the points along 45° diagonals. Use the [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) to calculate the distances:

```js
rd1.push(rx[y]*0.707 + ry[y]*0.707);
rd2.push(rx[y]*0.707 - ry[y]*0.707);
```

Use the random coordinates to generate the shape:

```js
let threshold = 400;
let rx, ry, drx, dry, rd1, rd2, drd1, drd2; 
do {
    rx = []; ry = []; rd1 = []; rd2 = [];
    for (let y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
        rx.push(random(10, width-20));
        ry.push(random(10, height-20));
        rd1.push(rx[y]*0.707 + ry[y]*0.707);
        rd2.push(rx[y]*0.707 - ry[y]*0.707);
    }
    drx = max(rx) - min(rx);
    dry = max(ry) - min(ry);
    drd1 = max(rd1) - min(rd1);
    drd2 = max(rd2) - min(rd2);
}
while (drx < threshold || dry < threshold || drd1 < threshold || drd2 < threshold)

beginShape();
stroke(255);
fill(25, 255, 255,100);
//noFill();
for (let y = 0; y < rx.length; y++) {
    vertex(rx[y], ry[y]);
}
endShape(CLOSE);
```

```js
let noOfShapes = 1;

function setup(){
    createCanvas(1240, 1754);
    noLoop();
    background(0,230)
    colorMode(RGB)
    rectMode(CENTER);
    strokeWeight(3);
}

function draw(){
    for(let x = 0; x < noOfShapes; x++) {
       
        let threshold = 400;
        let rx, ry, drx, dry, rd1, rd2, drd1, drd2; 
        do {
            rx = []; ry = []; rd1 = []; rd2 = [];
            for (let y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
                rx.push(random(10, width-20));
                ry.push(random(10, height-20));
                rd1.push(rx[y]*0.707 + ry[y]*0.707);
                rd2.push(rx[y]*0.707 - ry[y]*0.707);
            }
            drx = max(rx) - min(rx);
            dry = max(ry) - min(ry);
            drd1 = max(rd1) - min(rd1);
            drd2 = max(rd2) - min(rd2);
        }
        while (drx < threshold || dry < threshold || drd1 < threshold || drd2 < threshold)
      
        beginShape();
        stroke(255);
        fill(25, 255, 255,100);
        //noFill();
        for (let y = 0; y < rx.length; y++) {
            vertex(rx[y], ry[y]);
        }
        endShape(CLOSE);
    }
    stroke(255);

    for(let x=20; x<= width; x = x+20){
        blendMode(DODGE);
        //fill(200,200,200)
        stroke(255);
        beginShape();
          vertex(x, 0)
          vertex(x, height+20)
        endShape();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```